# Can't compile libs from bintray repository , looks like it's block my country IP

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin, bintray, jcenter

Looks like Bintray Blocked Iran's IP , then i can't compile libraries with this repository.
Is there any alternative repository ? or any other ways to use bintray jcenter's libs ?

Comment: Can you access Bintray's UI?

Comment: No it's blocked in iran ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm from Iran too, you should set proxy in android studio setting and you vpn. when you do that you see in your gradle.properties some lines like below:

```
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=156966
systemProp.https.proxyUser=ir33898
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
```