# I have some errors in gradle sync - android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have android studio v1.4 and have some errors in gradle sync.

in first I gave this Error:

> Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please
>   configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.

I searched in google and found that I must turn on offline work in global gradle settings

after that I gave this Error:

> No cached version listing for com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.+
>   available for offline mode.

for solving this I found that I must manual download the intended file and add it to android studio.

but I dont know exactly what file I must download ? and from where ? and how add to android studio ?

*build.gradle(project: test)* :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.+'
        classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.+"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

*build.gradle (module: app)* :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.saeid7laptop.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile project(':Material-Animations-master')
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle couldn't find com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675787/gradle-couldnt-find-com-android-databindingdatabinder1-0-rc0)

Comment: Though, if you are getting connection timeout, you may just want to check that you can connect to [jCenter](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.databinding.dataBinder/view), which is where you would download the jar files for offline-use.

Comment: If you are downloading a new package, you cannot turn on "offline work".  btw, are you on behind a proxy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The solution

The problem ended up being solved by the proxy settings in Android Studio. Those can be found in the Preferences window and it looks like this.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35560387/2308683) was also provided as a solution.

[image: proxy prefs]

---

#### To include a JAR file

> I found that I must manual download the intended file and add it to android studio, but I dont know exactly what file I must download?

The error tells you to download `com.android.databinding:dataBinder` (any version)

> and from where?

Here is the latest version on [JCenter](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.databinding.dataBinder/1.0-rc4/view#files/com/android/databinding/dataBinder/1.0-rc4). Just download the JAR file using the "Files" link towards the middle-right of the page.

> how add to android studio ?

Since you have this in your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Just move the JAR file into the `libs/` folder of the module you need to use the DataBinding library in.

Comment: I downloaded the file: _dataBinder-1.0-rc4.jar_ and moved into my project libs folder: _workspace/test/app/libs/_ . but again give me same error: **No cached version listing for com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.+ available for offline mode.** . even I maked a folder called _libs_ in my module folder (_Material-Animations-master_) and copy that file into that folder. but again give me same error !! exactly where must I copy this file ?

Comment: In the same module (directory) as the `build.gradle` and `src/`, you should make the `libs/` directory. And if you did put it there, then you can should be able to get out of offline mode and delete the line that says `classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.+"`

Comment: my problem didn't solve. can you connect to my pc by team viewer and check my problem ?

Comment: I *could* connect by teamviewer, but I'm at work, so I'm sure that's not a good idea. You said you added the libs folder into the Material Animations module. Why? That is a library, that I assume you cloned from GIthub? Unless you are adding features to it, you shouldn't touch those files at all.

Comment: ok I only add the file to app/libs folder not library folder but again give me same error :( - do you have telegram? if you have please contact me. username: Dash_saeid

Comment: Don't have telegram. You didn't answer the earlier question "are you on behind a proxy?" Are you able to use other android libraries and create other projects? Because I added the `classpath` line to my gradle file and it immediately worked, so your problem seems to be networking related.

Comment: I can't directly connect to bintray.com . because I'm from IRAN and we are under many boycott and these sites don't give us access and we must use proxy for connecting to many sites like bintray.com . I only have problem with libraries that need databinding. other types work good and without problem. now I want to add _dataBinder-1.0-rc4.jar_ file manually and offline to android studio. please explain me step by step how to add? for example must I make any folder with specific name in libs folder and move file in it or not ?

Comment: In one directory of your application you should have a `src/` and a `build.gradle` file. In that directory you make a `libs/` directory and you place the jar there. How did you download the jar file if you cannot connect to bintray?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107165/discussion-between-saeid-and-cricket-007).